# DataRepeater Control WinForms remove dotted line

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datarepeater

I have a `DataRepeater` control in a WinForms application.

The question is simple: how can I get rid of the dotted line that always appears when an item is selected?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens if you set `_dataRepeater.ItemHeaderVisible = false`. Since item headers are not visible, the repeater shows this dotted line in order to show which is the current item of the repeater.

Turns out there is actually a simple way to achieve this:

```
_dataRepeater.ItemHeaderVisible = true;
_dataRepeater.ItemHeaderSize = 0;
```

Which will achieve the same but without the dotted line.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately removing the dotted lines is "currently" not possible. (and probably never will be)

`DataRepeater` control is a pretty cool and useful control but it seems to have some issues and limitations.